Flyway Unsupported Database: PostgreSQL 17.0
Flyway does not support Postgres 17, before it was 16 and the same error message occurred, I have changed the dependencies several times and it remains the same. Finally, I installed db 17 and the latest version of the flyway dependency 10.20.1, and it continues to give the same error. I don't know what to do anymore, anyone to help?
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>10.20.1</version>
    </dependency>

I tried changing the dependencies and the database

You're most likely missing the additional dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>

Remember to provide the right version.

Replace core dependency with DB specific dependency
If you are using gradle
dependencies{
    ...
    //implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core") <- not required
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql")
}

For Maven users.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>


I had to go back to PostgreSQL version 16.6 for now.


Sometimes it's very tricky and cumbersome to manage all dependencies and configurations for Flyway database migration for PostgreSQL. I also encountered a problem to incorporate this part. But I overcame this by adding those dependencies and configurations.

First add those dependencies to POM.XML file
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.7.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-database-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>

Second add those configuration to application.yml file:
flyway:
  enabled: true
  # locations: classpath:db/migration # If necessary.
  baseline-on-migrate: true
  baseline-version: 1

Hope you will get rid of this problem.
